# И еще происхождение — "раболепствовать"

Tags: этимология

И еще одно слово интересует: "раболепствовать". Интересно, "лепота" — это "красота". А какое же отношение это слово имеет к понятию "унижаться", "подлизываться"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение морфа **-леп-** в слове *раболепие* совпадает с аналогичными в *великолепии* и *благолепии*. "Произведенное кем-то действие". Лепить ~ создавать, производить, делать ~ при помощи специфических движений или иных действий...  Например, лепить пельмени или пирожки, *лепить горбатого*, лепить кинообраз, снежную бабу, куличики из песка.
Если получается красиво, то можно сказать - *лепота* (дельная работа), если наоборот - *нелепость*.
Раболепие - "приличное рабам поведение, угождение, повиновение".
Не будьте ничьими рабами, даже своих желаний.